# how to create user profile in ionic with firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and Angular. I am developing an order placement app, but I m having trouble with creating a new user profile.

I m following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uESqBwFVf1Q&t=307s), but data is not saving in Firebase. Also, I already have a list in firebase with name orders.

**profile.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Profiles } from "../../models/profile/profile";
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage {

  profile = {} as Profiles
  // ref:any;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    // this.ref = afDatabase.list("Profile");
  }

  createProfile(){
    const user = this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
      this.afDatabase.object(`Profiles/${auth.uid}`).set(this.profile)
      .then(() => {
        // this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)

      });
      console.log(user);
    })
   }
}
```

**models/profile/profile.ts**

```
export interface Profiles {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    eventName: string;
    hall: string;
    booth: string;

}
```

**profile.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title> Create Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating [(ngModel)]="profile.firstName" ngDefaultControl>First Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating [(ngModel)]="profile.lastName" ngDefaultControl>Last Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating [(ngModel)]="profile.eventName" ngDefaultControl>Event Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating [(ngModel)]="profile.hall" ngDefaultControl>Hall #</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating [(ngModel)]="profile.booth" ngDefaultControl>Booth #</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button block (click)="createProfile(Profiles)">Create Profile</button>
</ion-content>
```

[This what i m getting on console after submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYWUd.png)

One more thing in last i have also integrated firebase login system with my app which is not logging out so, not sure if its creating a problem.

Plz guide me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: did you check whether auth.uid have  value or not by console log it?

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: console.log(auth.uid);

Comment: yes its showing an id.

Comment: Why are you passing Profiles as an argument? `createProfile(Profiles)`

Comment: my bad i couldn't check before posting. i have remove now but problem is still the same.

Comment: it is not necessary to pass the Profiles object via click event, you can access it through this.Profiles. try this query, this.afDatabase.database.ref('/Profile').child(auth.uid).set(this.profile);

Comment: @Sarasa Gunawardhana its not working..

Comment: run the code without  "const user =" . assign it to const variable. this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
      this.afDatabase.object(`Profiles/${auth.uid}`).set(this.profile);
    })
   }

Comment: i have already tried this but not working..

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you've just said to my answer. I believe you want to store some data in real-time db. If so, you better fix your template as I recommended.

Comment: i meant i was trying with argument first then i removed this argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, your Two-Way data binding is not working properly. That's why `profile` gives you an empty result.

Re-locate all the `[(ngModel)]` directives into `ion-input`, not in `ion-label`.

Comment: Great it worked.. only thing is its not adding multiple data value. previous values are replacing with the new one any hint?

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Don't forget to accept the answer so that others could get some help in the future.

Comment: That's a totally different question. The set method will replace the current value in the database with the new value specified as the parameter. You should use either a push method or use an update method to maintain the previous data. Please take your time and go through reading the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs/rtdb).

Comment: i accepted your answer but its not showing publicly due less than 15 reputations. Anyway thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @HarisBinZahid 15 reputations for an upvote. I'm talking about the accepting the answer. You'll see the check mark.